# DTD to XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I have this DTD:

`<!DOCTYPE recipes [
     <!ELEMENT recipes (Recipe+)>
     <!ELEMENT Recipe (Title,(Ingredients*|Preparation?),Comments?,
     Nutrition,Fat,Carbohydrates,Protein)>
     <!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT Ingredients EMPTY>
     <!ATTLIST Ingredients
     name CDATA #REQUIRED
     amount CDATA #IMPLIED
     unit CDATA #IMPLIED>
     <!ELEMENT Preparation(steps,filling?,dough?,sauce?)>
     <!ELEMENT steps (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT filling (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT dough (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT sauce (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT Comments (#PCDATA)>
     <!ATTLIST Nutrition
     Calories CDATA #REQUIRED> 
     <!ELEMENT Fat EMPTY>
     <!ATTLIST Fat fat CDATA #IMPLIED>
     <!ELEMENT Carbohydrates EMPTY>
     <!ATTLIST Carbohydrates carb CDATA #IMPLIED>
     <!ELEMENT Protein EMPTY>
     <!ATTLIST Protein prot CDATA #IMPLIED>

   ]>`

And I want to convert it to XSD but I don't understand how do I create attributes for all elements and how will be the entire DTD to XSD? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your DTD has no element defined for Nutrition, but if thats added then it looks something like this as an XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2017 - Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7084 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="recipes">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Recipe"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Recipe">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Title" />
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element ref="Ingredients"
                      minOccurs="0"
                      maxOccurs="unbounded" />
          <xs:element ref="Preparation"
                      minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="Comments"
                    minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element ref="Nutrition" />
        <xs:element ref="Fat" />
        <xs:element ref="Carbohydrates" />
        <xs:element ref="Protein" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Title"
              type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Ingredients">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="name"
                    type="xs:string"
                    use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="amount"
                    type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="unit"
                    type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Preparation">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="steps" />
        <xs:element ref="filling"
                    minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element ref="dough"
                    minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element ref="sauce"
                    minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="steps"
              type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="filling"
              type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="dough"
              type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="sauce"
              type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Nutrition">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:attribute name="Calories"
                    type="xs:string"
                    use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Comments"
              type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Fat">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="fat"
                    type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Carbohydrates">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="carb"
                    type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Protein">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="prot"
                    type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]